# IE displays the csv file instead of downloading

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jboss, struts2, download

I have a `.csv` file I want to allow users to download. This is a static file and I have set a hyper-link to the file.

It works fine on Firefox and chrome but in IE the csv file is shown in the browser instead of being downloaded.

All the solutions I've found requires the file to be sent via the server. But I feel that for serving a simple static file this is too much. Surely there must be an easier way.

I'm having a struts web app hosted in a JBoss server.

Any solutions?

Comment: Send the header: `Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=abc.csv`.

Comment: I don't think I can do it in html or javascript. Can I?

Comment: No, you would need to configure your webserver to send that header across. Sorry, I have no idea how you'd do that with jboss.

Comment: I did some searching and couldn't find anything usefull..

Comment: _I have a .csv file I want to allow users to download_ . Download from server, right? Or from where are you serving this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to add `mime-mapping` to your `web.xml`

```
<mime-mapping> 
  <extension>csv</extension>
  <mime-type>application/octet-stream</mime-type> 
</mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [stream result type](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/stream-result.html).  So your `struts.xml` config might contain something like:

```
<result name="success" type="stream">
  <param name="contentType">text/csv</param>
  <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
  <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="document.csv"</param>
  <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
</result>
```

There's an example at http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-download-file-example/

Comment: I already know this. But my question is do I have to run it through an action just to serve a static file? Surely there must be a better way..